# RTCPeerConnection candidates doesn't have a valid IPV4 address instead it has some .local address in it

Tags: webrtc, ip-address, ipv4, sdp, rtcpeerconnection

candidate:4031277258 1 udp 2113937151 fc10cb5a-f63b-4e15-81b5-3b8291facf8f.local 53215 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999

Above you can see the sample of the candidate generated

fc10cb5a-f63b-4e15-81b5-3b8291facf8f.local - How to fetch the IPV4 address from this? Why do I get this?

Comment: can you provide more information pls?

Comment: I get this candidate from the RTCpeerconnection.onicecandidate event in Chrome 76 and windows 10 OS. I am not getting a valid IPV4 address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an mdns hostname which Chrome is returning instead of a private IP these days. See [the PSA](https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/discuss-webrtc/6stQXi72BEU/twDfpwQ4DAAJ) for details.

You can not resolve it in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way by which I can ignore/remove that .local candidate in SDP that is sent to server? (without SDP munging) ? 

If there is no other way and only by SDP munging I can remove that candidate, then, will it work in Chrome?

Could you please suggest the best possible way to handle this?

Comment: you can try interpreting event.candidate.candidate.address (when available) in the onicecandidate and drop the candidate. When talking to a server that shouldn't do much harm.